# NRQL IF statement to select wanted value

Tags: performance, newrelic, nrql

I'm trying to get one result from query in NRQL, when external is bigger than 0 then it should return average(external), if not average(thirdparty). If that was SQL, it would be easy.

```
SELECT  average(externalDuration) FROM Transaction...
```

What I want:

```
SELECT IF(externalDuration>0,average(externalDuration), average(ThirdPartyConnection))FROM Transaction...
```

I don't know if it's even possible

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible, [since October 2022](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/the-if-function-is-now-available-in-nrql/190375):

```sql
SELECT average(if(
  externalDuration > 0, 
  externalDuration, 
  ThirdPartyConnection))
FROM Transaction
TIMESERIES auto
```